# Substitute all rows in a column to NA

Tags: r, syntax, na

Probably this is a simple problem, but I really can´t deal with that.

I am trying to put `NA` in all rows in `df$start`:

```
start  end   ok
100    200   yes
200    320   no 
230    300   no
```

I had tried `df[df$start] <- NA` but it seem to enter in one eternal loop.

My expected output:

```
   start  end   ok
    NA    200   yes
    NA    320   no 
    NA    300   no
```

Comment: Along to what @nrussell said you can also use `df[, "start"] <- NA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DF <- data.frame(
  start=c(100,200,230),
  end=c(200,320,300),
  ok=c("yes","no","no"),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
##
DF$start <- NA
DF
  start end  ok
1    NA 200 yes
2    NA 320  no
3    NA 300  no
```